# How to add application to Azure

Tags: azure, sharepoint-online

We have a console application which get data from a webservice and process it and then updates the items in a sharepoint list. Now we would want to upload this console application to Azure function?

I uploaded the release folder inside the wwwroot in KUDU. But seems like everything time I run the test, it always picks the run method from run.csx file?

Is it possible to incorporate the application into Azure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 3 options:

1. Use a batch Function
2. Use a C# Function but leverage the Process class object.
3. Use pre-compiled Functions.

Here's a similar GitHub thread with more information: https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/issues/42

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Is it possible with TimerTrigger/?

Comment: Yes, you can use Timer-Trigger as well.